# Typeorm - Create Postgres IDENTITY Column with EntitySchema

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

With *Typeorm*, I know that I can create a Postgres `IDENTITY` column like this:

```js
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('identity', { generatedIdentity: 'ALWAYS' })
    id: number;
}
```

But how can I do the same thing with an `EntitySchema`? This is what I have:

```js
const UserSchema = new EntitySchema<User>({
    name: 'user',
    columns: : {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            primary: true,
            generated: true
        }
    }
})
```

The `generated` property also allows 'uuid', 'rowid', and 'increment' as options, but these when I generate the migration they all result in `SERIAL` being used. Except for 'uuid', but I don't want a UUID. Here's example output:

```js
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`
        CREATE TABLE "Users" (
            "ID" SERIAL NOT NULL
        )
    `);
}
```

Comment: Having 'rowid' and  'increment' is strictly an option within your obscurification manager (Typeorm). Those **do not exist** in Postgres. Typeorm is converting them to a valid Postgres definition. Which is itself just a short cut for `create sequence` then use that sequence as the default for an integer column.